# I am getting the following error:Value cannot be null. Parameter name: reportParameters.Any ideas how to fix it?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I created a report using VSS reportviewer. This report has one parameter - a username.

The idea is that when a user clicks the `Print` icon to print a report, only records belonging to him/her will be displayed for printing, based on his/her logged in username.

I tested the .rdlc with hardcoded values and it works fine.

I am trying to integrate this report with my .net app and I am running into the following error:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: reportParameters
```

This error is on this line:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
```

Relevant data is below.

```
    Protected Sub btnUser_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnUser.Click
        which.Value = "U"
        Call Run_Report("")
    End Sub

Sub Run_Report(ByVal sel As String)
    ReportViewer1.Reset()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Dim params(0) As ReportParameter

    Select Case which.Value
        Case "U"
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("MyReporttSet", ObjectDataSource1.ID))
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "MyReport.rdlc"
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
            ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(params)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks alot in advance.

Comment: You never assign a value to `params`; you declare it (`Dim params(0) As Report Parameter`, but you never give it a value.  BTW, wouldn't `Dim params(0)` result in a zero-element array?

Comment: where you pass value in parameter

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the line

```
Dim params(0) As ReportParameter
```

you are creating a reportParameter object but not initialazing it.
see if it has a constructor then you could call

```
Dim params(0) As New ReportParameter()
```

then params won't be nothing

Comment: I have tried assigning this a value but I am getting an overload error. Do you have any specific examples?

`                params(0) = New ReportParameter("Username", Session("userName"), False)`

Comment: `Session` returns an `Object`, which you'll need to cast to `String` to use as the 2nd parameter in the constructor:  `params(0) = New ReportParameter("Username", Session("userName").ToString(), False)`

Comment: or you could try `Dim params As New ReportParameter()`

Answer (score 0):

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlcust.SelectedValue) Then
    param(0) = New SqlParameter("@custnam", ddlcust.SelectedValue)
Else
    param(0) = New SqlParameter("@custnam", DBNull.Value)
End If
```

Comment: OP is not using `System.Data.SqlClient`, they're using `ReportViewer` and associated classes from `Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms`, so this answer is not correct for this question.